# Understand why session_end was called

Tags: c#, asp.net, global-asax, sessionend

I'm looking for a way to intercept the reason why the event session_end in the global.asax was called, especially I would like to catch the event when the Session.Abandon() was called... is there a way?

I must do some operations only when the session expire, and some other operations when the command Session.Abandon() is explicitly called

Thanks and sorry for my poor english

Comment: Could you elaborate on why you want to do this?

Comment: Session_End event is fired when Session.Abandon() is called. Is this what you are looking for or something else ?

Comment: I've added more information

Comment: I believe you can still access the session object in the `Session_End` event, so when you call Abandon, add a session property too, then you can check it later.